# Reuse Instance Names for Different Objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Simple question: how can I reuse instance names for different objects (obviously on different frames)? I really want to be able to use the same instance name for all my scenes, "ground", even though these ground instances are of different classes. I really don't want to have to go about naming them "ground0", "ground1", etc.I realize that there are ways around this, but I would hate to fool around with all that extra work. So that being said, how do I reuse the instance name "ground" without having this warning thrown at me?:

```
Menu, Layer 'ground', Frame 1   Warning: The instance name 'ground' is declared on an object of type Ground but there is a conflicting use of the instance name 'ground' on an object of type Ground2.
```

And by the way, I realize that an instance is supposed to be an occurrence of a specific object, but to be honest I don't quite see the point in not being allowed to reuse instance names when appropriate. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall how finicky Flash was, it may have something to do with how you created the "ground" instance on those frames.

By that, I mean:

- Did you create one instance first, and then created new keyframes afterwards (meaning: the same instance would be used in all keyframes), or...
- Did you begin by creating your empty keyframes first, and then drag-dropping / pasting one "ground" instance in each frames? (meaning: in this case, it would likely be treated as 3 separate instances).

I'm not sure if this assumption is correct, but Flash doesn't necessarily tie instances to layers, as in "Oh, ground is on Layer 1, therefore every frames should reuse the same instance...". In a perfect world, I agree this would make sense. But from the early versions of Flash when it was mostly targeted to animators, where anything goes (from having multiple shapes and instances on the same frame, from re-arranging the depth of groups / instances on one frame/layer), it's still making the assumption that if you drag / copy an item from the library to the stage, it doesn't necessarily mean they are the same instance. Instead, you have to babysit Flash by creating more keyframes (or tween keyframes depending on your need) after the frame with the existing asset instance you want to reuse.

Again, the above is an assumption based on my experience - but if you did enter the "ground" instance-name manually for each instances found on each frames, chances are you previously copy/pasted or dragged new instances to those frames.

Does it sound like something you may have done?

**EDIT:**

If you have "ground" assets across a few frames, which are instances of different Symbols, then that definitely would trigger those Warnings you've been getting. I'm not sure where you can turn those off (Preferences? Project Publish settings? Advanced AS3 settings maybe?).. but regardless, here's a way that may work for you, programmatically.

Since each frames have a unique instance, with each instances named "ground", you could create a helper function to work like the `.getChildByName("ground")` method (and to be honest, I'm not sure if that method would work right-off the bat, you could try). You would need to for-loop through the given MovieClip's children (In your Menu's children, in your case I believe?), and check `if(child.name==theNameInQuestion) return child;`.
That being said, I can't guarantee this is THE proper solution (didn't test), as I don't know how you're navigating the frames at runtime (play/stop/gotoAndPlay/gotoAndStop/etc), and that may affect which "ground" instance is available at a given time. Internally, Flash does `addChild/removeChild` to swap out those various "ground" instances as it cycles through the frames, it's not a simple `visible=true/false` toggle (AFAIK).

**EDIT 2:**

This could be what you need?

[image: Short GIF video showing the AS3 Advanced Settings to disable Stage instance declarations]

Comment: Thank you @bigp for your quick response. I had know idea layers played a role in this, that's fascinating. As to your question of how these objects came into being, I began with a single mc "Ground" on the first scene, and then I duplicated this class and named it "Ground2". However, I attempted to have both objects share the same instance name of "ground". But Flash wouldn't have this since they were different classes.

Comment: Ah yeah, that would do it (since they were diff. Symbol Instances, or Classes as you put it). But If you still want to access each ground instances (regardless of the Class / Symbol Item they are an instance of), you can also programmatically find the instances by instance OR class name. I can elaborate in my answer (will edit).

Comment: I see what you're saying, but my end goal is to be able to call on both with the same instance name, if that's even possible. Is there a way to clear the instance's association with its class after using it? For example, scene one the instance name "ground" is associated with the Ground class. Then perhaps before moving on to the second scene, the instance name "ground" is cleared from use and then recalled on the second scene to an instance of the Ground2 class? I apologize if this is getting hard to understand.

Comment: Getting tricky to understand, but I'll try to :) - So in other words, in code you want to be able to store a reference to whatever the "ground" instance points to (the first time), and yet maintain a reference to whichever "ground" instance the timeline's playhead is landed on at any given time?

Comment: Maybe this will make more sense: "Is there a way to take remove an instance name in Flash with code that had been added manually before hand? This would solve the problem, and free the instance name for use in the future."

Comment: I see, that may have something to do with the Advanced AS3 settings... screengrabbing / posting in a bit...

Comment: Sounds complicated, do you have any idea of how we could do this?

Comment: Edited: posted a short GIF animation of the setting in question that you could try disabling.

Comment: The effect should be that even if you declare a public variable/property `ground` in the code, it won't have any association with the "ground" instances on the stage. It would fall to the dev's responsibility to store a reference of the desired "Ground" movieclip to the `ground` property.

Comment: brilliant! I'll give this a shot

Comment: shoot, what you said seemed like it would solve everything, but unfortunately I'd still have to some how identify the ground mc and assign it the instance name, so in reality it would be about as much work as giving out different instance names ("ground0", "ground1" etc). Great idea though. Another alternative that would also take a bit more time would be creating a variable "ground", and individually defining the variable to be the proper instance when the need arises.

Answer (score 1):

If any programming language if you want to reuse instance name variables you simply type them with the top most superclass type. In your case that would be:

```
var ground:DisplayObject;
ground = new Ground!();
ground = new Ground2();
//etc ....
```

Edit: If using property panel you can't use the same name for 2 objects as there will be no way to differentiate between them. So an error will be correctly thrown. 
Now if you want to use in code only one name same principle as shown above applies:

```
var ground:DisplayObject;
ground = ground0;
ground = ground1;
//etc ....
```

Then you can safely use in code the variable ground.

Comment: I don't think the OP was referring to the AS3 languages' instances (of a class) itself, but the instance-name entered via the Property Inspector panel in Flash Pro (CS# / CC).

Comment: Is there a way to take remove an instance name in Flash with code that had been added manually before hand? This would solve the problem, and free the instance name for use in the future.