# Can't transfer to another frame after initial gotoAndStop();

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cs6

Hello I'm trying to make a flash website that that has menus. But the problem is gotoAndStop(); doesn't work after transferring to another frame making it impossible to select items in that sub menu. Here's what I'm talking about.

Let's say I picked flash works, and it goes to that frame, after that i can't select any of the items in the second image even though I already have an event listener to it.

First image:

[image: 1st image]

Second Image: I can't click anything on this part. This is what appears when I click flash works.
[image]

Here's my code.

```
//this is the flash works button
flashworks_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goflashworks);
function goflashworks(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(2);
}

//let's say i picked basic animation
basicanimation_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gobasicanimation);
function gobasicanimation(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(10);
}
```

EDIT

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();
//homepage
home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gohome);
flashworks_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goflashworks);
aboutdev_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goaboutdev);

//flashworks
basicanimation_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gobasicanimation);
layersandsymbols_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, golayersandsymbols);
interactive_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gointeractivebutton);

//about developer
profile1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goprofile1);
profile2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goprofile2);

//basic animation
shapetween_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goshapetween);
motiontween_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gomotiontween);
classictween_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goclassictween);
back_flashworks_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goback_flashworks);

//layers and symbols
guidelayer_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goguidelayer);
masklayer_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gomasklayer);

//amazing effect button
amazingbuttoneffect_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gobuttoneffect);

//function home page
function gohome(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
function goflashworks(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
function goaboutdev(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(3);
}

//function flashworks
function gobasicanimation(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(10);
}
function golayersandsymbols(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(11);
}
function gointeractivebutton(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(12);
}

//function about developer
function goprofile1(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(13);
}
function goprofile2(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(14);
}

//basic animation function
function goshapetween(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(20);
}
function gomotiontween(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(21);
}
function goclassictween(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(22);
}
function goback_flashworks(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(2);
}

//layers and symbols function
function goguidelayer(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(23);
}
function gomasklayer(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(24);
}

//interactive button function
function gobuttoneffect(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(25);
}
```

Comment: What's likely going is your objects from the previous frame are unloaded when you change frames, if they are loaded again, the click listener may not be reapplied.   Please explain the context of your code better,  eg: the code your showing, where is that in relation to your buttons and other frames

Comment: If I could view the images I could help you out, but they aren't showing on my computer. And @LDMS has a good thought, I recently had that problem: [Reuse Instance Names for Different Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476856/reuse-instance-names-for-different-objects/29477270?noredirect=1#comment47117418_29477270)

Comment: I don't know what you mean but if I clicked the flash works it goes to the frame where there's another menu. That's where I can't select the items.

Comment: Here are the images. http://imgur.com/viPGZdU,mMW85fi#0 , I also added the whole code I am working on just in case.

Comment: As LDMS touch on, I suspect the buttons you are adding listeners to are not there when you add the listeners. So when you change the frame, there are no listeners on the buttons there. If you want to keep using timeline stuff, I would move the listeners for a specific "page" to the same frame as the graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I managed to solve the problem. It turns out that I need to separate the action script of the buttons in the different frames in my project, because the first thing I did before I solved it is that I put all the button instances in only one frame of the action script layer.